# Can vectors share the same memory space?

Tags: c++

Consider this program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::vector;

int main(){
    vector<vector<double>> A; A.reserve(3);
    
    vector<double> row1 = {0, 0, 5};
    vector<double> row2 = {0, -3, 0};
    vector<double> row3 = {1.5, 0, 0};
    
    A.push_back(row1); A.push_back(std::move(row2)); A.push_back(row3);
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++){
            std::printf("%-7.2f", A[i][j]);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
}
```

In the Xcode debugger, it's easy to see that by the time the for loop is reached, `row2` is empty (it's contents 'stolen' by `std::move`), whereas `row1` and `row3` were only copied, and still maintain their values.

My question is exactly this: does the object `A[0]` point to the exact same memory location that `row1` points to at this point? In other words, is `row1`'s contents in a **copy-on-write** state, where as soon as either `row1` or `A[0]` modify their contents a copy is created, but in the meantime, they share the memory containing `{0, 0, 5}` and there is nothing additional allocated.

I am asking this because I am computing the determinant of a matrix, passing in a `const std::vector<std::vector<double>> &`, and I don't want any additional memory used, but rather, the memory of that object itself.

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't do copy-on-write, it's copied immediately.

Comment: Is there anyway I could invoke copy-on-write @HolyBlackCat ?

Comment: This question have the feel of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is the original problem that lead up to this question?

Comment: You can implement it manually, on top of e.g. `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am computing the determinant of a matrix, passing in a `const std::vector<std::vector<double>> &`, and I don't want any additional memory used, but rather, the memory of that object itself.

Comment: Why would a regular pointer not be sufficient @HolyBlackCat ?

Comment: Why not a `vector<double>*` @user4581301 ?

Comment: Because manually managing memory is hard, and shouldn't be done if possible.

Comment: I wouldn't use nested vectors to represent matrices in the first place, use a single long vector of size `W*H`. To pass it to a function, pass a pointer to the first element, width and height, and finally the number of elements in a row (normally same as weight, but can be larger if you're passing a submatrix).

Comment: I think I see what you mean @HolyBlackCat . Do you mean like the array I had up in my post, where the access would look like `vector[i*cols + j]`? What do you mean by weight vs. row though? And would I pass a pointer to the vector itself? I feel like a reference would suffice, no?

Comment: In this case, imagining a 3 x 3 matrix, where the 3 rows are contiguous, to pass in a 2 x 2 sub-matrix (cofactor of row 1 and col 1), it would be the 5th, 6th, 8th, and 9th positions in memory. Do you have any idea how I would do that?

Comment: @user8393252 A pointer to element is more versatile, since it doesn't force the user to use a vector. *"What do you mean by weight vs. row though?"* Imagine you want to pass a submatrix of a matrix to the function (not sure if it makes sense in this specific application). Then you would need to know the width of the submatrix you're passing, and the width of the actual enclosing matrix (you would multiply `i` by the latter).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see what you mean. Basically, you're saying you need some way to know of the sub-matrix and what positions those are in the main matrix, so you only access within the sub.